# Semi-norms for Schwartz-Bruhat space over Q_p

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nt.number-theory

I'm an analyst beginning to do some work over the p-adics, in particular work with spaces of functions from $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\mathbb{C}$. The Schwartz-Bruhat space in this case is given by the space of locally constant functions with compact support. I was wondering if anyone knew of some canonical family of seminorms that people use in this space to define the topology.

Comment: Typically people don't think about this kind of space as having a topology at all (at least, not in the literature that I know), the reason being that the natural topology with which to equip it is the finest convex topology.  (If we fix a particular compact supporting sest, and a particular radius of local constancy, then we get a finite-dimensional space, and the entire space is the inductive limit of these spaces; the corresponding inductive limit topology seems the most natural choice to me, and this is the finest convex topology, since it a limit of finite-dimensional spaces.)